# wordpress date format change function

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am using below function getting dates from advanced custom fields pro plugin

my below code displays the dates from options ,

i want date format is different

```
 <!--event_start_date-->
            <?php if( get_field('event_start_date') ): ?>
            Event start date:
            <?php the_field('event_start_date'); ?><br/>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!--Event end date-->
            <?php if( get_field('event_end_date') ): ?>
            Event end date:
            <?php the_field('event_end_date'); ?><br/>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

i have used below code to change the format but not working , here `the_field('event_start_date');` directly displaying without print/echo

```
$new_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime(the_field('event_start_date')));
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: Try to replace  $new_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime(the_field('event_start_date')));
echo $new_date;   with  $new_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime(get_field('event_start_date')));
echo $new_date;

Comment: no luck its , working format but not converting existing date it is showing the start date of function 01-Jan-1970 , actually my date function displaying 30/11/2017 like this , i want like 30-November-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct way is to use ob_get_clean() to capture the output, like this:

```
<!--Event end date-->
<?php if( get_field('event_start_date') ): ?>
Event end date:

<?php 
ob_start();

the_field('event_start_date');
$date_string = ob_get_clean();
$new_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date_string));
echo $new_date;    
?>
<br/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is a bit overkill. Its best if you can find a function in the plugin that returns the data rather than outputs it.

Looking through the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) for acf plugin, the function get_field() does this.

According to the acf documentation, the date is stored a bit differently.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

```
$date_string = get_field('event_start_date',false,false)
$date = new DateTime($date_string);
$new_date = $date->format('d-M-Y');
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: no luck it is showing the date 01-jan-1970 like this

Comment: How do you want it to be like?

Comment: present is 30/11/2017 i want like 30-nov-2017

Comment: You should check if the field name is correct and the date set is too. The code will give an output date in the format d-M-Y.

Comment: the field is direct displaying value not able assign to or pass to date format

Comment: I've edited the answer with the field you mentioned in the question. Just check if it works.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do. You said that it shows as 01-jan-1970 which is the correct format that you need.

Comment: get_field('event_start_date')  = 30/11/2017; this is my value , your value is 
get_field('event_start_date')  = 01-jan-1970;How it is correct value.. yes the format is correct the value is wrong because its taking the default value of date function its starting value, have you understand what i am saying

Comment: Did you confirm that the field has the correct value ? This could happen if the value being returned in the date is null or an unrecognisable string

Comment: Just see the edit. You can refer the acf documentation link above and see why it was not working before.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have faced the same issue for converting date formate from the ACF field. so I used the simple WordPress method and it's working for me. like this:

```
$startdate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'event_start_date', true);
```

and then change formate you want:

```
date("jS", strtotime($startdate));
```

> event_start_date is my acf field name.

and its working for me.