# Changing Date Form with <?php the_field('date'); ?>

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to change the date format for one element of one of my site's pages.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php
/*
Template name: Auctions Diary
*/
get_header(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'flatsome_before_page' ); ?>

<style scope="scope">
    #pagination a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: .97em;
        letter-spacing: .03em;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bolder;
        text-align: center;
        color: currentColor;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-radius: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 1em;
        text-shadow: none;
        line-height: 2.4em;
        min-height: 2.5em;
        padding: 0 1.2em;
        max-width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #24691b;
        border-radius: 99px;
    }
    .det-link {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #0a612b;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 70px;
        border: 1px solid #2c3691;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .det-link a{
        color: #0a612b;
    }
    .det-link a:hover {color: #fe1307;}
</style>

<div id="content" role="main" class="content-area">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[section padding="0px"][page_header title="Auctions Diary" bg_color="#7a9c59"][/section]'); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col small-12 large-12">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <?php

                    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type'         => 'auctions_diary',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'meta_query'        => array(
                            array(
                                'key'           => 'auction_status',
                                'value'         => 'active',
                                'compare'       => '='
                            ),
//                             array(
//                                 'key'           => 'auction_date',
//                                 'value'         => date('d-m-Y') . ' 00:00:00',
//                                 'type'          => 'DATE',
//                                 'compare'       => '>=',
//                             )
                        ),
                        'meta_key' => 'auction_date',
                        'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
                        'order' => 'ASC'
                    ));
                    $date = "";
                    $status = true;
                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                    
                    if ($date != (string) date('F Y', strtotime(get_field('auction_date')))) {
                        $date = date('F Y', strtotime(get_field('auction_date')));
                        $status = true;
                    }

                    if ($status) {
                        echo "<tr><th style='border-bottom: 2px solid #24691b; font-size: 20px;'>". date('F Y', strtotime(get_field('auction_date'))) ."</th><th><br><br><br></th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
                        $status = false;

                    }
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong><?php the_field('auction_date'); ?></strong> <?php the_field('auction_start_time'); ?></td>
                            <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                            <td><div class="det-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Details</a></div></td>

                            <?php
                            $auction_id = get_field('auction_id');
                            $catalogues = new WP_Query(array(
                                'post_type'         => 'catalogue',
                                'meta_query'        => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'           => 'auction',
                                        'value'         =>  $auction_id
                                    )
                                )
                            ));
                            
                            echo "<td>";
                            if ((int) $catalogues->found_posts > 0) {
                                $id = get_the_ID();
                                echo "<div class='det-link'><a href='". home_url('/catalogues/?id=' . get_field('auction_id', get_the_ID())) ."&auction=$id'>Catalogue </a></div>";
                            }
                            echo "</td>";
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'flatsome_after_page' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Line 99 of the code is the bit I need to change:

```
                            <td><strong><?php the_field('auction_date');
```

Currently it is displaying the date in the format: June 17, 2021
But I would like to change this to: 17 June, 2021

I have updated the date / time settings in Wordpress but this does not seem to affect it.

I am also conscious that I need to change the format just for this line because the field 'auction_date' is used elsewhere in the code and I do not want to affect that.

Any idea how I can make this change please?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi JTG, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487938/5841606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
    date("d F, Y", strtotime(the_field('auction_date')));
?>
```

use **strtotime** to convert to date, and then use **date("d F, Y", $variable)** to change it into **17 June, 2021**

Comment: Thank you @Chandra-Syahputra

I tried replacing the line:

`<td><strong><?php the_field('auction_date'); ?></strong>`

with the code you suggested:

`<?php
    date("d F, Y", strtotime(the_field('auction_date')));
?>`

but nothing changes on the page. It still has the date format in 'June 17, 2021' format. I tried clearing the cache, viewing in an 'incognito' browser window but still nothing.

If I remove those lines of code though, the date does disappear from the page but nothing I do seems to change the date format.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564446/wordpress-date-format-change-function , i hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564446/wordpress-date-format-change-function one did it!